# What is the best way to remove old files and replacing with new in XCode?

Tags: xcode, directory, project, delete-file

I have an Admob folder with old admob files i need to replace with newer version. What is the best way to replace the folder with files in it? "Remove reference only" or "Delete". I've tried both but when i copy the new files into the project i would get files with the same name already existed error. Even after the files are no longer in the project and i still get the same error.

And sometimes after the files got deleted, the XCode project still link them in trash bin.

Answer (score 0):

You select the files that you want to remove and delete them, not remove reference.  Navigate to your project directory in finder and make sure that all admob files are gone, if they are not, drag them to the trash.  Drag your new files into xcode and make sure that copy if needed is checked.